# Skype python API

Tags: python, linux, web-applications, skype

Is there a skype web API or a python API that can be integrated into the Django APP.

Server : Python 2.4, linux RHEL5

Comment: FYI Skype API is dbus based on Linux and you can use it from any programming language with dbus. This is, basically, every programming language running on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.

Look at: https://developer.skype.com/

And: http://sourceforge.net/projects/skype4py/

Answer (score 1):

SkypeKit has a Python API, too and does **not** require the Skype client running. However, you do need a helper application - but on the skype developer website you can compile it for various architectures and operating systems.
If you don't have access yet it might take some time though to get it. I signed up for it when it was new and it took about 1 year until I got accvess - but maybe it's faster now (they charge something between $5 and $15 after to finally get access).

However, you REALLY need to upgrade your python version - 2.4 is **ancient**, that's almost like using IE5 nowadays...